# Custom Annotation for Toggling SqlSessionTemplate in MyBatis When Using Two Datasources

Tags: spring-boot, mybatis, spring-mybatis

I'm currently using Spring Boot 2.5 and MyBatis setup with multiple datasources.

I want to use a custom method-level annotation named `@ReadReplica` in my mapper interface and have MyBatis switch to my second datasource (`readReplicaDataSource`).

Something like this:

```
@Mapper
public interface MyMapper {

    @ReadReplica // uses readReplicaDataSource
    List<MyData> selectAll();

    int insert(MyData record); // uses primaryDataSource
}
```

Is this possible?

---

**application.yaml**

```
spring:
    datasource:
        driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
        password: ${DB_PSWD}
        username: ${DB_USER}
        jdbc-url: ${DB_URL}
    datasource-read-replica:
        driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
        password: ${DB_PSWD}
        username: ${DB_USER}
        jdbc-url: ${DB_READ_REPLICA_URL}

mybatis:
    mapper-locations: mapper/*.xml
```

**build.gradle**

```
implementation 'org.mybatis.spring.boot:mybatis-spring-boot-starter:2.1.4'
implementation 'org.mybatis.dynamic-sql:mybatis-dynamic-sql:1.3.0'
```

**PrimaryMyBatisConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@Slf4j
public class PrimaryMyBatisConfig {
   
    @Value("${mybatis.mapper-locations}")
    private String mapperLocations;
  
    @Primary
    @Bean(name="primaryDataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    SqlSessionFactory primarySqlSessionFactory(DataSource dataSource) {
        SqlSessionFactory sessionFactory = null;
        try {
            SqlSessionFactoryBean bean = new SqlSessionFactoryBean();
            bean.setDataSource(dataSource);
            bean.setMapperLocations((new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver().getResources(ResourceLoader.CLASSPATH_URL_PREFIX + mapperLocations)));
            sessionFactory = bean.getObject();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Error establishing primary SQL session factory {}", e);
        }
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    SqlSessionTemplate primarySqlSessionTemplate(@Qualifier("primaryDataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
        return new SqlSessionTemplate(primarySqlSessionFactory(dataSource));
    }
    
    @Bean
    @Primary
    public DataSourceTransactionManager primaryTransactionManager(@Qualifier("primaryDataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
        return new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource);
    }
}
```

**ReadReplicaMyBatisConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@Slf4j
public class ReadReplicaMyBatisConfig {
   
    @Value("${mybatis.mapper-locations}")
    private String mapperLocations;
  
    @Bean(name="readReplicaDataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource-read-replica")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }
    
    SqlSessionFactory readReplicaSqlSessionFactory(DataSource dataSource) {
        SqlSessionFactory sessionFactory = null;
        try {
            SqlSessionFactoryBean bean = new SqlSessionFactoryBean();
            bean.setDataSource(dataSource);
            bean.setMapperLocations((new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver().getResources(ResourceLoader.CLASSPATH_URL_PREFIX + mapperLocations)));
            sessionFactory = bean.getObject();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Error establishing read replica SQL session factory {}", e);
        }
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    SqlSessionTemplate readReplicaSqlSessionTemplate(@Qualifier("readReplicaDataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
        return new SqlSessionTemplate(readReplicaSqlSessionFactory(dataSource));
    }
    
    @Bean
    public DataSourceTransactionManager readReplicaTransactionManager(@Qualifier("readReplicaDataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
        return new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource);
    }
}
```

**ReadReplica.java**

```
@Documented
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface ReadReplica {}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to accomplish this by configuring custom `@MapperScan` annotations. Here is an example connecting mappers in different packages to different templates. The concept is similar for connecting to different datasources: https://github.com/jeffgbutler/mybatis-cockroach-demo/blob/master/src/main/java/com/example/cockroachdemo/MyBatisConfiguration.java